# MongoDB doesn't group properly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using mongoDB with .NET and for over a year, the same query worked properly.
For a single date range - `04.06.22. - 05.06.22.` query malfunctioned and didn't group only one product by ID, so I am getting 2 products with the same ID.

Query (will delete unnecessary params, to make it easier to understand):

```
                .FilterByCustomer(filter.CustomerId)
                .FilterByTerminals(filter.Terminals)
                .FilterByDateRange("FromLocalDateTime", "ToLocalDateTime", filter.LocalDateRange)
                .Unwind("SalesForSingleProductReports", false)
                .Unwind("SalesForSingleProductReports.RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency", false)
                .Group(
                    @"  _id : {
                                ProductInfo: '$SalesForSingleProductReports.ProductInfo', 
                                CurrencyInfo: '$SalesForSingleProductReports.RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency.CurrencyInfo'
                        },
                        RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency: {
                            $push: {
                                Revenue: {$sum: '$SalesForSingleProductReports.RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency.Revenue'},
                                }
                            }    
                        }")
                .Group(@"_id : '$_id.ProductInfo',
                        RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency: {$push: {
                            CurrencyInfo: '$_id.CurrencyInfo',
                            Revenue: {$sum: '$RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency.Revenue'},
                        }")
                .Project(@"_id:0,
                          ProductInfo:'$_id',
                          'RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency': 1")
                .Compile();
```

The result that I am getting is multiple products, but one is duplicated and has different revenue values, but same ID:

```
[{
   "productInfo": {
            "productId": "id-111",
            "productName": null,
            "productInternalCode": "internal-111",
            "productCategoryId": "prod-cat-111",
            "productCode": null,
            "brand": null,
            "countryCode": null
        },
   "revenueAndSalesPerCurrency": [
            {
                "currencyInfo": {
                    "currencyId": "curr-Id",
                    "code": "EUR",
                    "symbol": "€"
                },
                "revenue": 1680,
            }
        ]
   },
   {
   "productInfo": {
            "productId": "id-111",
            "productName": null,
            "productInternalCode": "internal-111",
            "productCategoryId": "prod-cat-111",
            "productCode": null,
            "brand": null,
            "countryCode": null
        },
   "revenueAndSalesPerCurrency": [
            {
                "currencyInfo": {
                    "currencyId": "curr-id",
                    "code": "EUR",
                    "symbol": "€"
                },
                "revenue": 3080,
            }
        ]
   }
]
```

Here's one record from the collection on which actions are done:

````
    "_id" : ObjectId("id-string"),
    "CreatedAt" : ISODate("2021-11-10T10:14:10.116Z"),
    "UpdatedAt" : ISODate("2021-11-10T10:14:10.116Z"),
    "CreatedByUserId" : null,
    "UpdatedByUserId" : null,
    "Version" : null,
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "ReportType" : "AggregatedSingleProductSalesReportForTerminalAndDate",
    "ReportId" : "report-id,
    "CustomerId" : "cust-id",
    "FromUtcDateTime" : ISODate("2021-11-01T23:00:00.000Z"),
    "ToUtcDateTime" : ISODate("2021-11-02T22:59:59.999Z"),
    "FromLocalDateTime" : ISODate("2021-11-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "ToLocalDateTime" : ISODate("2021-11-02T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "TransactionIds" : [ 
        "trans-id-1", 
        "trans-id-2", 
    ],
    "TerminalId" : "terminal-id",
    "LocalDate" : "2021-11-02",
    "SalesForSingleProductReports" : [ 
        {
            "ProductInfo" : {
                "ProductId" : "prod-id",
                "ProductName" : null,
                "ProductInternalCode" : "internal-string",
                "ProductCategoryId" : "prod-category-id"
            },
            "RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency" : [ 
                {
                    "CurrencyInfo" : {
                        "CurrencyId" : "euro-curr",
                        "Code" : "GBP",
                        "Symbol" : "£"
                    },
                    "Revenue" : 180,
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "ProductInfo" : {
                "ProductId" : "prod-id-2",
                "ProductName" : null,
                "ProductInternalCode" : "internal-string-2",
                "ProductCategoryId" : "prod-category-id-2"
            },
            "RevenueAndSalesPerCurrency" : [ 
                {
                    "CurrencyInfo" : {
                        "CurrencyId" : "euro-curr",
                        "Code" : "GBP",
                        "Symbol" : "£"
                    },
                    "Revenue" : 90,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: Please provide some sample input data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sure, I edited question, I put a single record from that collection, if you think additional data is still needed, please inform me